# Building a private API with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, backend

Hello me and friends are planning on taking on a big project. My two friends are going to be building iOS and Android apps and I will be making the server back end. I recently started developing with RoR and have fallen in love with Ruby. Now here are my questions:

**Little more background:**
I only want a private API for the android and iPhone app. I do NOT want a full fledged OAuth authentication process. Doing some research I think I will go with basic HTTP authentication.

**1. My App uses cookie based authentication meaning a cookie has to be passed with each subsequent request. So will my friends need to have to store a cookie and on each subsequent request to the server send the cookie along with it?**

**2. How do I go about making the API private? I know in OAuth there are consumer secret and consumer key.  I know if anyone could simply figure out the URL schema they will be able to have access to the API. How do I protect my back end from request from unknown users? (Hard coding strings in the Apps themselves?, Checking headers for device type?)**

**3. Should I only build the API now and worry about a web app later? Or would it be too horrific of an experience to go back and build a web app (Although I really do actually want the web app to be more significant than the mobile app**

Answer (score 3):

Here is a great article explaining exactly what you're looking for : securing an API without setting up a full OAUTH provider :

http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/

Works great (even if the solution is finally not so far from oauth ;)

Comment: the article link specified is no longer working, here is the same article I found http://acaasia.blogspot.com/2013/04/designing-secure-rest-web-api-without.html but unfortunately there is no code examples